# Issue with media file name in install4j

Tags: install4j

I have two media files:

1. 64 bit media file **with** jre bundled.
2. 64 bit media file **with out** jre bundled.

In-fact, both media files are same but only difference is with jre bundling and with out jre bundling.

When I tried to build both media files I am getting following error message:

***Media file PatchManagement\Agent\installer\trunk\media\PatchAgent_windows-x64_1_0.exe has already been created.***

Please help me to come out from the above issue.

Regards,

Jagadeesh Musham.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the wizard for the media file with the bundled JRE, go to the

Customize project defaults->Media file name

step and configure a different media file name.